# How do you Install DNX on OSX using Homebrew?

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

Hello Since the big rename of k to dnx I have no idea how to install the tools on my mac?

the documentation on the dev branch has not been updated to reflect the big rename

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/dev

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The homebrew-k was updated recently to support dnvm. Here the instructions:

- Install Homebrew if it is not already installed.
- Run command  `brew tap aspnet/k` to tap the ASP.NET 5 related git repositories. If you had already tapped the repo for previous releases, run  `brew untap aspnet/k` to delete the old commands and tap again to get the updated brew scripts
- Run command  `brew install dnvm` to install dnvm. This will automatically install the latest DNX package from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 feed
- Run command  `source dnvm.sh` on your terminal if your terminal cannot understand `dnvm`

**EDIT**

Homebrew-K was renamed to Homebrew-dnx so now you should use

```
brew tap aspnet/dnx
```

If you tapped `aspnet/k` it is probably not a bad idea to untap it (`brew untap aspnet/k`) and update brew (`brew update`)

Comment: Should the tap be renamed to dnx?

Comment: Possibly. At the moment it contains formulas for both kvm and dnx. Once dnx officially replaces kvm and the kvm formula goes away it would be a good time to rename.

Comment: @MaduAlikor - your dreams came true - the tap was renamed to dnx.

Comment: @Pawel followed this but still getting that `k` and `kpm` commands are not found. Is that somewhere else now?

Comment: @AndrewS - have you done the `source` thing (source `dnvm.sh` or source `kvm.sh`) depending on which one you want to use (hint kvm is going away soon)?

Comment: @Pawel yeah, got that sorted out. [All the `k` commands are now `d` commands, e.g. `kpm build` => `dnu build`](https://github.com/OmniSharp/Kulture/issues/28#issuecomment-97198228).

Comment: yeah. I was not sure if the scripts were not added to your profile or you were using old commands...

Comment: Life saver! They should put your 4th instruction in the setup page.

Comment: @YoussefSami I believe the formula tells you to run `source dnvm.sh` after you install dnvm.