# How to get the "dnu" command working on OS X?

Tags: .net, macos, asp.net-core, dnx

Just downloaded and installed [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) on OS X 10.10.3.

I've managed to partially follow the [installation instructions for ASP.NET 5](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/ASPnet5).

What I fail with is when the instruction tells me to call

```
dnu restore
```

When doing this in my terminal, it says:

> -bash: dnu: command not found

I've found a somewhat [similar question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29398877/107625) which unfortunately did not help me.

**My question:**

How can I make the "dnu" command work on OS X?

**Update:**

Someone marked my questions as the duplicate of the SO question I linked to by myself.

Now SO forces me to edit my question to proof that it is not a duplicate. So basically that is me right now:

[image: I have no idea what I'm doing]

I hope this satisfies the needs of SO to *not* close my question as a duplicate since my understanding is that it is no duplicate.

Comment: Same issue here. This issue may apply. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/499

Comment: Wow, @JedGrant that did the trick. Will update my question with what helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398877/how-do-you-install-dnx-on-osx-using-homebrew/29399460?noredirect=1#comment48018238_29399460

Comment: Woot first time I ever answered a SO question :P

Comment: You should be able to run the 'dnu restore' command (and other dnx commands) from the Command Palette ('⌘-P') in Visual Studio Code, instead of running it from Terminal.

Comment: I don't want SO to be filled with meme

Comment: `dnvm upgrade` was the part I was missing.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To answer my own question:

What helped, was [Jed Grant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952630/how-to-get-the-dnu-command-working-on-os-x?noredirect=1#comment48026580_29952630) and link to [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/499).

I did the following in a terminal:

```
source dnvm.sh
dnvm upgrade -u
```

And suddenly the "dnu" command was available so that I could run

```
dnu restore
```

As the installation instructions told me.

Comment: Where does dnvm.sh come from or where would it be located? Just following the instructions and encountered the same problem (also have no idea what I'm doing).

Comment: Nevermind, got sorted, need to learn to read... http://stackoverflow.com/a/29965989/609176

Comment: it's just like Magiccc

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and ran `dnvm upgrade -u`. Afterwards, I could successfully run `dnu restore`. Thanks!

Comment: Did you also manage to compile the source on OS X? (Using `dnu build`)

Answer (score 19):

Bit of a noob answer, but it might help someone. If you're on OS X, make sure you follow the [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5) carefully! I completely missed some OS X specific instructions under the heading "Installing ASP.NET 5 and DNX". I read the heading and thought "I've already installed this".

The instructions for OS X points to:

https://github.com/aspnet/home#os-x

It says to run the following homebrew commands:

```
brew tap aspnet/dnx
brew update
brew install dnvm
```

After this succeeds, the following text is output in the console:

> Add the following to the ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file:
>
> source dnvm.sh

I added it to my `.bash_profile` and now `dnu restore` works from my project directory!

In general, I found the steps on the ASP.NET 5 docs page much clearer than the Visual Studio Code page. Acronyms are explained and screenshots of many steps are present.

[Installing ASP.NET 5 on Mac OS X](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html)

[Your First ASP.NET 5 Application on a Mac](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 6):

For those trying to get this working on windows with the same problem, you just need to run `dnvm upgrade` from command prompt. `dnu` will now work.

Comment: this just worked for me on a mac, seems the easiest answer to me

Answer (score 3):

After read this issue in GitHub:

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/499)

Run `nano ~/.bash_profile`

Add:

```
export PATH="~/npm-global/bin:$PATH" 
source dnvm.sh
```

Edit: It not solve the problem at all... when I try to update the Nuget Packages using dnvm command (is the purpose of dnx restore), I have other error:

> Error: Could not find latest version from feed
>   https://nuget.org/api/v2

Comment: Oh my god, I did all... But no way... Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: .... also on a mild digression, what the hell were they thinking calling an IDE ... well a text editor for now, "code"? Searching "visual studio code" is getting me nowhere.

Comment: oh the command is "dnu restore" btw and you have to cd into the right directory

Comment: Yes, I saved it, restarted terminal and restarted computer :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76583/discussion-between-sacredgeometry-and-chemitaxis).

Answer (score 1):

Steps to get dnu command working.

Open Visual Studio Command prompt and run following commands:

1. check list of available DNVM using command `dnvm list`
2. dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 (change based on your requirement)
3. dnu restore